# Out of curiosity, how many ChatGPT answers are accepted before they get deleted?

Tags: discussion, chatgpt

I am flagging such answers every day and in some rare cases, I see some of them accepted.

I am wondering if it's easy for moderators to get the number of accepted answers.

I am simply curious to know the percentage of accepted answers among the AI generated ones. I expect it to be very low but maybe it's higher than what I am expecting (considering that I am only active in [the CSS tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css)).

Comment: It's worth noting that the ones that _are_ accepted often have comments suggesting that the asker doesn't fully understand what they're saying.  I don't have a good idea of the overall percentage, though.

Comment: The closest question to that would be "what percentage of people accept answer without first verifying if they work or not". That's basically very similar, since that's one of the main reason why some people might accept those answers. It's hard to really know a good, factual percentage of either though, unless people admit it...or you look at the comments as Ryan suggested

Comment: Even getting a ballpark figure would require a staff member to write a query to run internally. We (mods) don't really have any tools that would enable us to search through previously helpful mod flags related to ChatGPT/AI content on answers of a particular type (_e.g._ accepted answers).

Comment: @NordineLotfi ehhh, it *is* right sometimes.  The trouble is that it is also quite often very wrong while _sounding_ like it knows what it's talking about.

Comment: It's not unusual to answer a question, have it accepted and up-voted by the OP and then get a comment from them which indicates that they haven't understood a thing, or even read your answer. I don't expect the AI spam answers to be any different.

Comment: @Lundin very true. It is simply not the job of Stack Overflow to teach, only to inform. Answer acceptance is a virtually useless (and misunderstood) statistic in general. It won't satisfy any kind of curiosity because you simply can't know how realistic the statistics based on it are.

Comment: Another question could be how many posts deleted as Spam or R/A were accepted. ;-P

Comment: Don't know why a answer to this post was deleted, but it gives some stats and links to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/390376/375553). It's better than nothing.

Comment: I'm not even sure if mod search would be able to give any answers. When I did a mod search (on another site), it only showed 2 deleted accepted answers in the last 10+ years, which is obviously wrong. I went to an answer that I remember being accepted when it was deleted, and the checkmark was gone (but I think timelines never show unaccepts). There must be a process that removes the checkmark from deleted answers.

Answer (score 1):

Of the 114 ChatGPT (or other LLM) answers I flagged from 12/22 to 5/23 before the strike, [1 was accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75423012/6243352), but it turned out it wasn't AI generated anyway.

See [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/390376/399876) which breaks down my flags and methodology.

Answer (score -32):

As a partial answer to your question, I tried pasting all of my unanswered questions into the Stats / [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour) Stack Exchange site in ChatGPT 4, and I would say that for 10 out 12 of the ChatGPT 4 answers I would have given them a check mark as being mostly or completely correct and being helpful, whereas I currently did not give any of the human-written replies a check mark. (Usually they do not answer the questions, or are beating about the bush; in some cases they were also plain wrong.) Some more results of my experience in looking at the reliability of the output of ChatGPT 4 can be found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387575/examples-of-chatgpt-being-right-and-wrong-on-stack-exchange/390348#390348).

I doubt if moderators have a good estimate available of the % of ChatGPT answers that would be flagged as correct. Currently they will be picking up and flagging mainly the answers that are clear examples of abuse, whereas answers where ChatGPT assisted in providing an answer, without it being disclosed as such, will not be picked up. Nobody would ever have flagged my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48119360/performant-2d-sdl-or-opengl-graphics-in-r-for-fast-display-of-raster-image-using/76472961?noredirect=1#comment134865427_76472961) e.g. if I hadn't disclosed that part of the code had come about via the use of ChatGPT 4. I did flag that one as the correct one before moderators took it down—three times, no less. The current answer and code I rewrote a bit to avoid it being deleted a fourth time.

I should also say there is a huge difference in the reliability of ChatGPT 3.5 vs ChatGPT 4, evident also from the [published benchmarks](https://openai.com/research/gpt-4). So what moderators are picking up may be mainly unedited output from the free-tier ChatGPT 3.5 system, not the paid version ChatGPT 4.

Comment: Yes, i too would have gave all of my own answers checkmarks

Comment: Can you stop that _"GPT4 is better than 3.5"_ crusade of yours already? It's still unreliable. It's still hallucinating stuff. It's still ___nowhere near___ good enough. Your constant insistence that GPT4 isn't a problem is ___completely___ missing the point as to _why_ ___all___ GPT-generated content is _bad_.

Comment: @Cerbrus Your "all GPT-generated content is bad" crusade is also pretty tiring. Just get me some proper data on reliability, collected in a fully blind way, as suggested here, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384410/how-often-does-chatgpt-give-an-incorrect-answer-to-an-se-question, and then come back...

Comment: Look at the score on that question and on the answers... They don't support your argument.

Comment: And besides, even ___if___ the answers are any good, users can go get them ___from the AI___ they don't need to be on SE.

Comment: And __yet again__, you're completely ignoring the weak points GPT4 shares with all other models.

Comment: @Cerbrus We already established that votes on this platform for answers have little bearing with them being right or wrong. Bizarre how you would prefer most answers to never receive a good reply over having to accept a user having gotten a tiny bit of inspiration off ChatGPT & using that to formulate a decent answer.

Comment: No, _you_ established that you disagree with this platform's userbase, so you're dismissing its opinion because you think GPT is just awesome. Then ___go use it___. Just don't pollute SE with it.

Comment: No answer is _infinitely_ better than a well-formatted _wrong_ answer.

Comment: I have been trying to use GPT4 in my programming workflow, through `Copilot Chat`, which has not been reliable.  **60-70% of the code was complete gibberish.** Which tells me. the output for most output, will also be complete gibberish. `Copilot Chat` is GPT4 not GPT3.5

Comment: @SecurityHound I find ChatGPT4 a lot better for programming than Github Copilot or Bing Gpt, even though they all have a GPT4 base. Just different implementations... And if it's producing gibberish it's easy enough to tell...

Comment: Or… You can’t tell the output is wrong, inefficient, a bad practice or whatever, so you don’t know…

Comment: @Cerbrus Have you ever received a reply with a code suggestion on SO that you don't have to thoroughly check? How often did that solve your problem right away? Usually takes a lot of prodding too, along the lines of "ha but can you still change this" or use that package etc

Comment: @TomWenseleers eh, no, the answers I write are tested and verified. Something language models ___can not___ do. And how is that an argument in favor of GPT? _”It writes answers that need refining.”_ ___That’s the entire problem!___ Users don’t do that. They’re lazy. Do you even understand ___WHY___ SO banned language models?

Comment: _Just get me some proper data_ - would you care to reciprocate? Something in-context, not just the general data which isn't related to this site or its mission

Comment: @Cerbrus The answers I write are always tested and verified too, even if ChatGPT helped a bit. But I've received a lot of replies with nonworking solutions on SO where ChatGPT was not even remotely involved, I can tell you that. Like that response about RGL in my SDL/OpenGL question.

Comment: LLMs do happily write some benchmarking code. Testing if it works before posting it literally takes 10 secs...

Comment: I mean, you still seem to be missing the point. "sometimes a wrong answer is posted", has been a thing for as long as SO has existed. the problem is "sometimes" became 10 times an hour or more *per user using gpt* in december. Far more than the tools we have for dealing with quality problems can deal with. Your experience doesn't change that.

Comment: @KevinB But that was back in dec right, when quality was still a lot worse? According to the data that Philippe posted that phase has passed now? In the meantime these systems now got massively better and users learned to work with them too. Benchmarks on university entrance exam questions and maths exams went from bottom 10% to top 10%.

Comment: @TomWenseleers philippe's data is demonstrably wrong, by simply casually browsing SO for a few minutes.

Comment: Which is great, and pretty exciting, but still doesn't automatically make their use suitable for **this platform**. That seems to be the disconnect here. That you, personally, will dillegently check these answers before posting doesn't mean that there aren't plenty of others who will just use it as an opportunity to game the system, inevitably reducing quality. Until these things don't need checking, they're not likely to be welcome here

Comment: @Clive I feel that blatant abuse should be possible to filter out automatically. Really not rocket science to set up a system that can do that in an automated way without requiring any moderator intervention imho... And what should users do that do write good answers partly inspired by ChatGPT output? Keep quiet about that I suppose? Hardly ethical...

Comment: And if your definition of "blatant abuse" is "posting LLM-generated answers without checking for accuracy"? How would you filter that out?

Comment: @TomWenseleers - I have asked both ChatGPT 3.5 and ChatGPT 4 similar questions, both generated complete gibberish, despite a confirmation it did understand the topic.  I will go further in my statement, the code that was generated wasn't usable at all, until I fixed it likewise almost all the code I received from a human author on Stack Overflow was usable without having to fix it.  That is the difference between AI generated trash code and human generated code.

Comment: @Clive Well for any programming related answers (which is the single usage case where I would allow some ChatGPT output if verified) I think it would be obvious to do, as I pointed out here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390324/how-accurately-could-one-differentiate-between-simple-copy-paste-of-ai-generat/390362#390362. Users should be required to include reproducible code with output or benchmark (ChatGPT doesn't run code yet) & include some reputable sources. Both would ensure users did some proper verification for accuracy...

Comment: Here is the real problem, had I asked the question, and somebody else asked ChatGPT the answer and submitted the generated answer they wouldn't have been able to determine the ChatGPT answer was incorrect and complete gibberish.  It took me 3 and half hours to realize that ChatGPT was failing to produce workable code, and I thoroughly understand the subject (just no time), I had attempted to use Copilot Chat on.

Comment: @TomWenseleers if we can't reliably get people to test code, there's no way in hell we can reliably get them to generate "benchmarks" and include reputable sources. this is grasping at straws at this point.

Comment: @SecurityHound What programming language was that? And what sort of problems? Mine is mostly R & Python stuff. Maybe it's better at that, don't know. Can you post any examples?

Comment: I feel like this is in danger of going round in circles, and we're obviously missing a major point that the other is trying to make which connects all this together. So I'll bow out and wish you good luck. I will say though, as a cranky old programmer, I would say your faith in people to do what they're asked is a bit too strong :)

Comment: @KevinB Well but automatically kicking out any programming related answer that mentions ChatGPT but does not include the words "timings" or "benchmark" would not be exactly hard, would it?

Comment: @TomWenseleers You're assuming StackOverflow, the company, will build tooling to do this, when they haven't built any significant tooling to help with curating content for 8 years (other than the recent plagiarized content flag)

Comment: @TomWenseleers - I asked it VBA questions, it generated, complete gibberish. I asked it to generate C# code, based on a subject it seemed to understand, but the output was complete gibberish.  Keep it mind the code compiled, the code just failed to properly represent the subject, despite a confirmation within the same conversation of topic knowledge. I was actually just trying to get it to generate a shell of a code, because I am stressed and overworked, but it failed at even the most basic task and I wasted 3 hours trying to massage the output.

Comment: @KevinB Well that definitely needs fixing if SO would like to keep up in the current changing landscape. I would think that they are aware of this. I am willing to accept that not too much could change on the front of policies re GPT use if they can't fix that & keep relying exclusively on manual moderation...

Comment: Interesting that no one's said anything about LLMs using SO as a source for their models, and the fact that if we simply allow LLMs to answer questions, it will be yet more "blind leading the blind", or in this case "hallucinators leading the hallucinators". Imagine if LLMs were to generate questions...

Comment: @HereticMonkey I think in general that argument is overplayed. It was mainly github that was critical for the training of those models. And ultimately what's key is quality control on the posted answers, whether they are in part ChatGPT based or not - that should include good rating mechanisms for any answers (currently rating mechanism does not work well) & good mechanisms to kick out bad answers entirely (this can also be partly automated).

Comment: @PeterM, nice initiative the Edits from you to `ChatGPT&nbsp;4` and `ChatGPT&nbsp;3.5`, (and TomW the Answerer should have done "their homework" before posting...), but the "Convention" seems to be, when talking about different Versions of 'ChatGPT', => to use a Dash (`-`) before the Version Nb: => `ChatGPT-4` / `ChatGPT-3.5` / `ChatGPT-3`, or to mention once `ChatGPT`, and then use `GPT-4` / `GPT-3.5` / `GPT-3`.